# Unittesting Repositories using mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, repository

I'm trying to write unittests. It is the first time I'm doing this using repositories and dependency injection.

My unittest looks as follows :

```
[TestClass()]
public class PersonRepositoryTests
{
    Mock<PersonRepository> persoonRepository;
    IEnumerable<Person> personen;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        persoonRepository = new Moq.Mock<PersonRepository >();
        personen = new List<Person>() { new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Bart Schelkens", GewerkteDagen = 200, Leeftijd = 52, Type = "1" },
                                        new Person { ID = 2, Name = "Yoram Kerckhofs", GewerkteDagen = 190, Leeftijd = 52, Type = "1" }};

        persoonRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(personen);

    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetAll()
    {
        var result = persoonRepository.Object.GetAll();
    }
}
```

My repository :

```
 public class PersonRepository
{
    DatabaseContext DbContext { get; }

    public PersonRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        this.DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return DbContext.Persons.ToList();
    }

}
```

Now when I run my test, I get the following error :

"Can not instantiate proxy of class: CoBen.Dossier.DataAccess.Repository.PersonRepository.
Could not find a parameterless constructor."

So I am doing something wrong, but I'm not seeing it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Read the error message...

Comment: @Steve: i know what it says, I'm just not succeeding at adding the databasecontext

Comment: Bear in mind that when you mock the repository, the code in the repository is never called, as the mock 'intercepts' the calls and returns the values you have specified. So you can just extract the repository methods to an interface and mock that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mocking your system under test (sut), the PersonRepository, where as what you need to Mock is it's dependencies:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAll()
{
    // *Arrange*
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>(); 

    var mockContext = new Mock<DatabaseContext>(); 
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Person).Returns(mockSet.Object); 

    // Configure the context to return something meaningful

    var sut = new PersonRepository(mockContext.Object);

    // *Act*
    var result = sut.GetAll()

    // *Assert* that the result was as expected
}
```

It's a little bit "air code" as your question doesn't have much detail around how the DbContext bit is configured.

There is a [worked example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

That error is occuring because in your unit test you are mock the repository but your repository class seems to have a dependency on the datacontext.

You need to add a default contructor in your repository that does not have the datacontext as a dependency as per below:

public PersonRepository()

or mock the datacontext. Hope that helps

Comment: And what if I wanted to mock the datacontext as well ?

Comment: i would suggest for example to use a marker interface for your databasecontext.

Comment: If you are mocking the datacontext, then you would have to **not** mock the repository, as the datacontext mock would not be called by a mock repository.

Comment: for example   public PersonRepository(IDatabaseContext context)  . in your unit test you can then create a mock<IDatabaseContext> and set up your repository = new PersonRepository(MockDatabaseContext)(). Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try add a parameterless constructor :)

```
public PersonRepository(){}
```

Comment: But what if I want the constructor with the parameter? How would I inject the databasecontext?